# Node js throw exception in events

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am wondering how to throw an error or returning value from event.

My code looks like this:

```js
    _initConnection(){
        try{
            const errorValidation = this.errorValidation
            const HOST = "192.168.2.32"
            const PORT = 8282
            this.socket = net.createConnection(PORT, HOST)
            this.socket.on('data', function(data) {
                errorValidation(data)// throwing error
                console.log('Received: ' + data);
                return data
            });
            this.socket.on('err', function(err) {
                console.log('Connection'+err);
            });
            this.socket.on('close', function(e) {
                console.log('Connection closed');
                
            });
        }catch(err){
            throw err
        }
    }
```

But because of the event throwing error is impossible it crash the app what should I do?
Is using a Promies is a good guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, essentially, the same as [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

In your `try/catch` block you assign a function which will run, *in the future*, whenever there is a `data` event.

The `try/catch` block then finishes (as does the function it is inside).

Later, in the future, you want to throw an exception, but you can't catch it in the `try/catch` block you had because it doesn't exist any more. The security guard watching for trouble has packed up and gone home.

If you want to handle errors relating to the `data` event, then you need to do it **inside** the function that runs when there is a `data` event. It is the only thing available to do that at the right time.